# Forcing with c.c.c forcing notions, Cohen reals and Random reals

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, open-problems, forcing

I think the following question is due to Prikry:

**Question.** Is it consistent that any non-trivial c.c.c forcing notion adds a Cohen real or a Random real?

Is the question still open?  What partial results are known about this question (with references, please).

**Remark.** I have the following simple observation which might be well-know.

**Theorem.** Souslin hypothesis (SH) hols iff any non-trivial c.c.c forcing notion adds a new real.

**Proof.** One direction is trivial, since a Souslin tree, considered as a forcing notion, is c.c.c and adds no new reals.

For the other direction suppose  there is a non-trivial c.c.c forcing notion $P$ which adds no new reals. Let $B=R.O(P)$ be the completion of $P$. B is a c.c.c. complete Boolean algebra which is $(\omega, \omega)$-distributive, hence it is in fact $(\omega, \infty)-$distributive, thus it is a Souslin algebra, which implies the existence of a Souslin tree, and hence SH fails.

**Update.** Can anyone say the first place where the above question has appeared?

Comment: What about "Prikry reals"?  Fix an ultrafilter U on $\omega$, and let $(s,A) \in \mathbb{P}$ when $s$ is finite, $A \in U$, etc., same as Prikry forcing.  This is obviously c.c.c., so do you know if it is consistent that Prikry real forcing adds a Cohen real or Random real?

Comment: One can show that Mathias forcing  relative to an ultrafilter U adds Cohen reals exactly when U is not selective.

Comment: The question whether every Suslin ccc forcing notion adding a real must add a Cohen real or add a random real is problem 4.7 in Shelah's "On what I do not understand": http://shelah.logic.at/files/666.pdf

Comment: Check also the paper "Ccc forcing and splitting reals" by Velickovic, according to which every Suslin ccc forcing adds a Cohen real or is a Maharam algebra. It's also worth mentioning that the question whether every Maharam algebra is a measure algebra was answered negatively by Talagrand.

Comment: I believe the theorem in your question was proved by Jim Baumgartner.  I know that it was proved by me, quite some time ago, but then I was told that Jim had proved it considerably earlier yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you historical information. I think the theorem is just a simple observation, and I arrived to it, not by thinking on the above problem, but on "Foreman's maximality principle" which says "any non-trivial forcing notion either adds a real or collapses some cardinals". Note that a trivial consequence of this principle is that any non-trivial c.c.c. forcing adds a real.