# Strongly proper ccc forcing

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Is there an example of a strongly proper ccc forcing that is not equivalent to Cohen forcing?

Comment: Shooting from the hip, coding a subset of $\omega_1$ into a real?

Comment: I think this one fails.  The conditions are $(s,F)$, where $s$ is a finite subset of $\omega$ and $F$ is a finite set of almost-disjoint subsets of $\omega$ from a given collection of $\omega_1$ many.  Let $M \prec H_\theta$ be countable, and let $p \in M$ be a condition.  For any $q = (s,F) \leq p$ such that there is $A \in F \setminus M$, there cannot be a reduction of $q$ to $M$.  Because if $r \in M$, then $r$ there is $(t,G) \leq r$ in $M$ such that $t$ has some elements of $A$ above $\max s$, so is incompatible with $q$.

Comment: I think "strongly proper" might stand for different things across the literature.  Monroe means "strongly proper" in Mitchell's sense.  I.e. for club many countable $M$ and every $p \in M$ there is a $p' \le p$ which is an $(M,P)$-strong master condition; which in turn means that for every $p'' \le p'$ there is a $p''|M \in M \cap P$ such that all extensions of $p''|M$ in $M \cap P$ are compatible with $p''$.

Comment: @Sean: I've never heard "strongly proper" before, and the first Google result was your slides from a talk not long ago. And now I also saw that you two posted a paper on arXiv today. in any case, I didn't know that this definition existed or had different variants. But I did say that I shot from the hip with my suggestion (taking your slide about forcing with side conditions as something which can sometimes be strongly proper, and I figured that coding subsets is in some sense a Cohen forcing with side conditions, so it might just work).

Comment: @AsafKaragila my comment wasn't in response to your suggestion, I merely thought the question needed some clarification of terminology.

Comment: If there is a strongly proper ccc forcing which does not add a Cohen real, then, then should answer Prikry's well-known question. This is because such a forcing does not add Random reals. For Prikry's question see  [Forcing with c.c.c forcing notions, Cohen reals and Random reals](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146800/forcing-with-c-c-c-forcing-notions-cohen-reals-and-random-reals).

Comment: @Mohammad: I think that you're reading the question too literally with the last suggestion. I think the meaning of "Cohen forcing" here is adding any number of reals, not just one.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani all (nontrivial) strongly proper forcings add Cohen reals, since there will be countable models $M$ from $V$ such that $G \cap M$ is generic over $V$ for $P \cap M$ (where $P$ is the strongly proper forcing and $G$ is $(V,P)$-generic).

Comment: @AsafKaragila right, thanks for clarification

Comment: @SeanCox That's nice, thanks for noting this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes, and it follows from the following paper of Koppelberg and Shelah [Subalgebras of Cohen algebras need not be Cohen](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9610227).

In this paper, it is shown, for each $\kappa \geq \aleph_2,$ there exists a  non-Cohen complete subalgebra of $Add(\omega, \kappa)$.

This subalgebra, is c.c.c and strongly proper, as a projection of Cohen forcing, but is not isomorphic to Cohen forcing.

Comment: Natural follow-up question:  Does there exist a strongly proper ccc forcing of uniform density $\aleph_1$ that is not Cohen?

Comment: @MonroeEskew About the follow-up question: perhaps [this paper](http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/math.LO/9502230) of Shelah and Zapletal is of some relevance.

Comment: Also, these examples are all where for club many models $M$, $1_{\mathbb P}$ is a strong master condition.  I wonder if this is a necessary feature of strongly proper ccc forcing.

Comment: The paper in @tci 's comment, Shelah and Zapletal's _Embeddings of Cohen algebras_, has updated link https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9502230